# Replacing an input on a standard lightning record page with an LWC, not a custom edit page

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-lightning

I would like to create a standard lightning record page, not a custom one. Using the lightning app builder or dynamic forms. I would like to drag and drop all the fields that I want into this layout.  But for one of the fields, I would like to replace it with a custom picklist component that I created. So that the users can use my picklist to choose a value to store in that field. That way the users just click edit and then they see the edit page with my component as the input for one field.

I’ve only come across a couple of ways to handle this.

1. Create a completely custom edit record page using the lightning
   record edit component and then add my custom component to that page.
2. Creating a custom component that allows the setting of the field,
   but it needs its own save button. I don't see a way to set the field
   and allow the built-in save button that is on the page to work.

I've also not seen a way to create a custom record edit page where I can both use a defined page layout and then add my custom component.  If I could do that, it might work.  But it seems like the record edit page component forces you to code in all the fields you want displayed and the lightning form component doesn't allow you to add custom components.

Am I missing something?